# Why did my reputation change to 914?

Tags: support, reputation

When I saw today it was 12xx something but now it has gone back to 914,2 days ago it was 989.

Is there is bug in the system? If so,how do I get my reputation back?

Answer (score 3):

You can check https://askubuntu.com/reputation for a detailed report of changes to your reputation. ([Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation))

Comment: But it was first 12xx something,maybe the system failed to log it?

Answer (score 1):

Probably those votes were invalidated by our daily vote anomaly detection script.

There are no known issues with the rep system, however, there are near-constant attempts to game the system.